# Kafka monitoring JMX : choose some attributes

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, jmx

How can I select some attributes from monitoring of Kafka with JMX using `kafka.tools.JmxTool`?

Comment: You can answer your own posts. But don't put the solution in the "question" itself

Answer (score 1):

```
/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool --object-name 'kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=MyTopic'
    --attributes 'Count,MeanRate,OneMinuteRate' --jmx-url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:9999/jmxrmi
```